# Confirm Delete with Javascript and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

// function to get all categories from the db

```
function find_all_category(){

    global $connection;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `category`"; //getting data from db 
        $get_cat_details = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_cat_details)) { // fetch-array
        $cat_id=$row['catid'];
        $cat_name=$row['catname'];
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>{$cat_id}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$cat_name}</td>";
        echo "<td><a href='category.php?edit={$cat_id}'><i class='fa fa-pencil- 
               square-o' aria-hidden='true' style='color:purple;'></i></a> 
               </td>";      
        echo "<td><a class='item_delete' href='category.php?delete={$cat_id}'><i 
              class='fa fa-trash-o' aria-hidden='true' style='color:red;'></i> 
              </a></td>"; // contains class to be used in javascript
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

//javascript function for the confirm function

```
$(".item_delete").click(function()
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete ?");
)};
```

Not working,please help

Comment: The delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.
we can use delegated events to bind the click event to dynamically created elements.`$(document).on('click', '.item_delete', function() {
   return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete ?");
});`

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error use below code. You missed the opening `{` of the function.

```
$(".item_delete").click(function() {
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete ?");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but still no responce, it just deletes the category

Comment: Where's the syntax error?  This looks exactly the same as OPs code.

Comment: The OP doesn't have the starting `{ ` for the function.

Comment: The code does not give any errors it has zero effect on the table row

Answer (score 0):

You should have value of confirm in a variable like this

```
$('body').on('click', '.item_delete', function() {

   return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete ?"); // if you just want 
   // to return the confirm

   // or you can delete based on conditions as
   var statusDelete = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete ?");


  if(statusDelete  == "true"){
// call function to delete
   }
 if(statusDelete  == "false"){
// call function when cancel clicked
   }

};
```

Comment: The OP uses the return value to return it to the click event it seems.

Comment: it seems problm of event delegation. this code should work fine.